# converting pyspark dataframe fail on 'None Type' object

Tags: dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe 'data3' with many columns. I am trying to run kmeans on it except the first two columns, when I run my code , tasks always fails on TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' What am I doing wrong?

```
def f(x):
    rel = {}
    #rel['features'] = Vectors.dense(float(x[0]),float(x[1]),float(x[2]),float(x[3]))
    rel['features'] = Vectors.dense(float(x[2]),float(x[3]),float(x[4]),float(x[5]),float(x[6]),float(x[7]),float(x[8]),float(x[9]),float(x[10]),float(x[11]),float(x[12]),float(x[13]),float(x[14]),float(x[15]),float(x[16]),float(x[17]),float(x[18]),float(x[19]),float(x[20]),float(x[21]),float(x[22]),float(x[23]),float(x[24]),float(x[25]),float(x[26]),float(x[27]),float(x[28]),float(x[29]),float(x[30]),float(x[31]),float(x[32]),float(x[33]),float(x[34]),float(x[35]),float(x[36]),float(x[37]),float(x[38]),float(x[39]),float(x[40]),float(x[41]),float(x[42]),float(x[43]),float(x[44]),float(x[45]),float(x[46]),float(x[47]),float(x[48]),float(x[49]))
    return rel

data= data3.rdd.map(lambda p: Row(**f(p))).toDF()
kmeansmodel = KMeans().setK(7).setFeaturesCol('features').setPredictionCol('prediction').fit(data)

TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error comes from converting the `x`s to float because you probably have missing values

```
rel['features'] = Vectors.dense(float(x[2]),float(x[3]),float(x[4]),float(x[5]),float(x[6]),float(x[7]),float(x[8]),float(x[9]),float(x[10]),float(x[11]),float(x[12]),float(x[13]),float(x[14]),float(x[15]),float(x[16]),float(x[17]),float(x[18]),float(x[19]),float(x[20]),float(x[21]),float(x[22]),float(x[23]),float(x[24]),float(x[25]),float(x[26]),float(x[27]),float(x[28]),float(x[29]),float(x[30]),float(x[31]),float(x[32]),float(x[33]),float(x[34]),float(x[35]),float(x[36]),float(x[37]),float(x[38]),float(x[39]),float(x[40]),float(x[41]),float(x[42]),float(x[43]),float(x[44]),float(x[45]),float(x[46]),float(x[47]),float(x[48]),float(x[49]))
return rel
```

You can create a flag to convert each `x` to float when there is a missing values. For example

```
list_of_Xs = [x[2], x[3], x[4], x[5], x[6],etc. ]
for x in list_of_Xs:
    if x is not None:
        x = float(x)
```

Or use `rel.dropna()`

Comment: Thank you very much, I implemented this with a dropna function that delete all the missing values,then program can run normally.